# Microsoft 70-515 exam training?

Tags: asp.net

My company is ready to buy the study material and practice exams online. So please tell which is the best site to buy the material and online practice exams.

So far I have found "testking" materials to buy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The official training kit from Microsoft should be enough to pass the exam. The training kit includes the theoretical part (the book) as well as some practice tests (CD). Also there is probably a discount coupon inside the book so you can get a discount when applying for a test.

[Buy on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627401)

-- Pavel